# Howto read value of entry in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Can anyone please tell me, why I get the error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.lab1 = tk.Label(text="Abfahrtsort").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")
        self.start = tk.Entry(self).grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.lab2 = tk.Label(text="Zielort").grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="w")
        self.end = tk.Entry(self).grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Anzeigen", command=self.on_button).grid(row=2, column=1)

    def on_button(self):
        messagebox.showinfo(self.entry.get())

app = App()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Change `self.entry.get()` to `self.end.get()`. You are trying to use `get()` on a non-existent `self.entry`. Seeing that you have defined your entry field as `self.end` you need to change your messagebox statement to reflect the same. On top of that you need to use `grid()` on a new line separate from where you define your entry field.

Comment: If you had searched this site with that exact error message you would have found an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues here in your code. The 1st one is your `grid()` statement.

Change these:

```
self.start = tk.Entry(self).grid(row=0, column=1)
self.end = tk.Entry(self).grid(row=1, column=1)
```

To this:

```
self.start = tk.Entry(self)
self.start.grid(row=0, column=1)
```

and this:

```
self.end = tk.Entry(self)
self.end.grid(row=1, column=1)
```

The 2nd is your messagebox statement.

Change this:

```
messagebox.showinfo(self.entry.get())
```

To this:

```
messagebox.showinfo(self.start.get())
```

Or this depending on what entry you are trying to access:

```
messagebox.showinfo(self.end.get())
```

You will also need to correct the indention of your self.end and self.button to be inline with everything else in your `__init__` method.